# Series proof needed

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have following equations but I do not know the proof. Kindly provide the proof or give me some reference to look into. Here are the equations.

1- $\sum_{a=1}^{s+t-1}\sum_{b=0}^{a}x^b=\frac{1}{1-x}\left(s+t-1+x-\sum_{a=1}^{s+t}x^a\right)$

2- $\sum_{a=t}^{s+t-1}\sum_{b=0}^{a-t}x^b=\frac{1}{1-x}\left(s-\sum_{a=1}^{s}x^a\right)$

where $s<t, x<0.$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also a better title is needed.

Comment: Doing the first sum first, these look like truncated geometric series. Then maybe you can just mangle them around into this specific form? It doesn't look too bad because you have the 1/(1-x) pulled out on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that
$$\sum_{b=0}^ax^b=\frac{1-x^{a+1}}{1-x}$$
Now,
$$\sum_{a=1}^{s+t-1}\sum_{b=0}^ax^b=\sum_{a=1}^{s+t-1}\frac{1-x^{a+1}}{1-x}=\frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{a=1}^{s+t-1}\left(1-x^{a+1}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-x}\left(\sum_{a=1}^{s+t-1}1-\sum_{a=1}^{s+t-1}x^{a+1}\right)=\frac{1}{1-x}\left(s+t-1+x-\sum_{a=1}^{s+t}x^a\right)$$
The second one can be calculated similarly. I used the formula for the sum of a geometric series freely here.

Comment: perfect answer thank you